# Image not taking full height of container next to div with dynamic text

Tags: html, css, image, height

I am currently facing a problem while trying to make fit an image with full height next to a div that has text that isn't fixed.

I have tried setting max-width, max-height at 100% with no luck, also with background images and still can't find a solution.

Here is my markup:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 containerDivs">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>    
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do          
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim 
       veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi u</p>
        <a href="#"><i class="moreIcon white spinLeft"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <img src="img/image-1.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
  .containerDivs{           
        > div:first-child{
            background-color:grey;              
            padding: 20px;
            h2{
                font-family: 'Lounge-Bold', Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: 30px;                                                    
                letter-spacing: 6px;                    
                margin-bottom: 30px;
            }
            h2,p{
                color: white;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }
            p{
                line-height: 1.8;
                font-family: 'Lounge', Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: 16px;                        
            }
        }
        > div:last-child{           
            
        }
        
    }
```

Here is how it is looking in my browser right now:

[image: Full height problem]

So what I am missing is for the image to take the full height of the column, it is ok if part of the image is cropped, as long as it takes full height.

Comment: you can try play with the viewport height (`vh`) which may work. But I expect it will distort the image some what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Flexbox](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) to have the two div at the same height.

```
/* Add it to the parent */
.containerDivs{
   display: flex;
}
```

About the img, if you want it to take full height, i would recommand you to use background-image on the div :

```
.containerDivs>div:last-child{           
  background-image: url("path_to_your_image");
  background-size:cover;
}
```

Here's is a working JsFiddle : [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/b6tej45k/2/)

Comment: Hey Mathieu! Thanks a lot for your answer, seems like the only way is using display: flex, which I was avoiding because of cross browser issues, is there any other way this can be done without that display? WIll give it a try now, thanks in advance !

Comment: There are other methods, but they are a bit more complex. Take a look at 
[CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/) . Also, there might be a few cross browser issues with flexbox, but it's mostly supported : [Flexbox support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)